# Pandas dataframe/chunksize

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a large file of 5 gb

**filenme = 'sample1.csv'**

fewsamplerows : 
*145555,???? OOO Optima,,,,,???? OOO YYYYYY,GFGF,,,,APO Voggg,General Trade,Stupino,SELL Russia Branded,0,,,,,
302325,A2 General Enterprise,,,,, ,,,,, ,Affiliates,,SELL ARTHH,,,,,,*

now i want to add another row as a header in this file.

**updated file: 'sample2.csv'**

*mdcCustomerClientCode;mdcCustomerName;mdcCusGroup1Desc;mdcCusGroup2Desc;mdcCusGroup3Desc;mdcCusGroup4Desc;mdcCusGroup5Desc;mdcCusGroup6Desc;mdcCusGroup7Desc;mdcCusGroup8Desc;mdcCusGroup9Desc;mdcCusGroup10Desc;mdcCusGroup11Desc;mdcCusGroup12Desc;mdcCusGroup13Desc;mdcCusGroup14Desc;mdcCusGroup15Desc;mdcCusGroup16Desc;mdcCusGroup17Desc;mdcCusGroup18Desc;mdcCusGroup19Desc
145555,???? OOO Optima,,,,,???? YYYYYY,GFGF,,,,APO Voggg,General Trade,Stupino,SELL Russia Branded,0,,,,,
302325,A2 General Enterprise,,,,, ,,,,, ,Affiliates,,SELL ARTHH,,,,,,*

since it is a large file, i am not able to create a pandas dataframe and append a row on top as a header.

So i want to use pandas chunksize option. i am a newbie to pandas and hence requesting your inputs.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('tblViewPromotionDataVolume_202004070600.csv', chunksize=1000) 
for chunk in df1: 
    print (chunk)
```

What should be the code after this? I want a file as sample2.csv with a row appended on top as a header.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `pandas` for this as your file is just a plain text file (`csv` files are also plain text files)

You can open your file `sample2.csv` in a text editor and add the header row and save it. And then, in python -

```
with open('sample2.csv', 'a') as f:
    for line in open('sample1.csv', 'r'):
        f.write(line)
```